# Is casting between structs with different size allowed/safe in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, casting, type-conversion

I have some `struct`s like this:

```
struct myStruct0 {
    void(*deallocMe)(void*); // points always to "myStruct0_dealloc"
    uint8_t* someStuff;
    void* someOtherStuff;
}
void myStruct0_dealloc(void* structPtr) {
    myStruct0* s = (myStruct0*)structPtr;
    free(s->someStuff);
    free(s->someOtherStuff);
    free(s);
}

struct myStruct1 {
    void(*deallocMe)(void*); // points always to "myStruct1_dealloc"
    uint8_t* someStuff;
    uint64_t largeArray[4096];
    void* someOtherStuff;
    char* someRealOtherStuff;
}
void myStruct1_dealloc(void* structPtr) {
    myStruct1* s = (myStruct1*)structPtr;
    free(s->someStuff);
    free(s->someOtherStuff);
    free(s->someRealOtherStuff);
    free(s);
}
```

Both `struct`s and the pointers are allocated using malloc (and of course must not be NULL).

Is the following code safe?

```
struct genericForm {
    void(*deallocMe)(void*);
}

void deallocMyStructX(void* myStructX) {
    genericForm* x = (genericForm*)myStructX;
    x->deallocMe(myStructX);
}
```

Why do I want to do this?

I'll have an array of pointers to some `struct`s like the above and if this would work I have not to save the deallocator for each `struct`/pointer. This would really simplify my code.

Edit:
The structs can be completely different. The only thing they share is that they contain a function-pointer of the form `void(*)(void*)` as the first element.

Comment: What a terrible question title! Why not replace "following" by the thing that follows?!?

Comment: Using something like that is a very common way of handling a sort of inheritance using C structures. There's one problem with your code though, for it to really work the second structure needs to look *exactly* as the first structure, i.e. the common members must be declared in the exact same order.

Comment: Absolutely terrible, I think he should be shot.

Comment: An alternative would be to have a `struct genericForm` as first member in each of the other `struct`s. Maybe as an anonymous member.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well, this is the problem; the structs can be completely different. The only thing they share is that they contain a function-pointer with the form void(\*)(void\*) as the first element.

Comment: *if this would work I have not to save the deallocator for each struct/pointer.*  But you **do** have to save the deallocator - you just save it as part of the structure.  So you don't gain anything.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't have to pass the deallocator as a separate argument with the struct. This can get really confusing especially if you pass it around more than one time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is to access the first member of your structs, you should be fine. The offset of the first member is guaranteed to be 0, and if the first member is compatible across all structs (ie a function pointer), you should be allright. If you're going to dereference your structs and access other members, than you might run into problems due to padding. Adding placeholder members might solve that, but is arguably a tad inefficient.

If you don't have too many structs to worry about, a might be an easier solution here:

```
struct _data {
    int identifier;
    union {
        struct type_1 {} _t1;
        struct type_2 {} _t2;
        struct _generic {
            void (*dealloc_generic)(void *);//first member is dealloc function pointer
        } _gen;
    };
};
void dealloc_struct(struct _data * s)
{
    switch (s->identifier)
    {
        case 1:
            s->t1->delloc_t1_ptr(s->t1);
            return;
        //and so on
        default:
            //for generic-compatible structs
            s->_gen->delloc_generic(s->_gen);
    }
}
```

If the first member of your structs will always be a valid function pointer, then you could even write this:

```
void dealloc_struct(void *s)
{
    //cast s to function pointer, call it and pass the pointer as argument
    ((void (*)(void *))s)(s);
}
```

This should work, according to the standard (C1x §6.7.2.1.13):

> A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member [...] and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within as structure object, but not at its beginning.

Comment: Well, I might get *a lot of* different structs, so your code would get really complex very fast. But the sentence: "The offset of the first member is guaranteed to be 0, and if the first member is compatible across all structs (ie a function pointer), you should be alright." is what I needed! Ty 

Comment: @K.Biermann: Quoted the part of the standard that confirms that the first member will always be at offset 0, and added a one-liner that allows you to cast the struct, and call its first member directly

Answer (score 1):

> Is casting between structs with different size allowed/safe in C?

In general: no.  The addressing space of one structure may be entirely incompatible with another.

A solution is to put both structures in a `union`.

```
struct myStruct0 {
  void(*deallocMe)(void*);  //Common elements must be in the beginning with same type/order
  ...
}

struct myStruct1 {
  void(*deallocMe)(void*);
  ...
}

union genericForm {
  struct myStruct0 s0;
  struct myStruct1 s1;
}
```

A pedantic method would used

```
struct myStruct0 {
  ...
};

struct myStruct1 {
  ...
};

struct genericForm {
  void(*deallocMe)(void*);   //Common elements here
  union {                    // Anonymous union
    struct myStruct0 s0;
    struct myStruct1 s1;
  }; 
};
```

Comment: Then how does this sockaddr <-> sockaddr_in-thing work?
And you don't have any argument against "A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member [...] and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within as structure object, but not at it's beginning.", which is what I wanted to know; you're answer applies to the title but not really to my question. I admit the title is a bit misleading; if you have some improved wording I'll fix it.

Comment: @K. Biermann The title, post and answer do not tie well together, even if the selected answer meets your goal.  Many (most) architectures store structure  in the same address space allowing casual address conversion.  C does not specify that arrangement, but allows it.

Comment: @K. Biermann Instead `myStruct0 a[3]` could be at address `red:0, red:1 red:2` and  `struct myStruct1 b[3]` could be at address `blue:0, blue:1 blue:2` even though they differ in size as "red" data is in `sizeof(myStruct0)` land and "blue" data is in `sizeof(myStruct1)` land.  And code just cannot convert between those 2 pointers.  By making a union, both sub-structure types will exist in the same land.

Comment: Well I understand your point but putting all possible structures into an union is sadly not possible because I don't even know which structures might be passed. If someone creates myStruct2 the code would require an update, which is not possible every time. I think I'll stay with Elias Van Ootegem's way and if this won't work I'll pass the pointers additionally with the structures... Thank you anyway 

Comment: @K. Biermann  Good luck.  Having been through this many times, the trouble with _not_ making the union (2nd style above), is that sooner or later one of those "new" structures does not have the same leading fields (as time goes on, it will be more than 1) (or some coder assumes more are common fields than truly are) and code breaks mysteriously at run-time (or post deployment time) rather than at the convenient compile time.  At minimum, suggest wrapping that lone `deallocMe` field as the initial (and so far only) member of a `struct` called `common` to highlight its special use.